# INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED when using modals in buttons v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've got the following code, however I receive `Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.`.

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.customId === 'partnerbutton') {
    let user = interaction.user;

    const Modal = new Discord.Modal()
      .setCustomId('partnerego')
      .setTitle('$nake Partnership');

    const input1 = new Discord.TextInputComponent()
      .setCustomId('invito')
      .setLabel("l'invito del server")
      .setPlaceholder('https:/discord.gg/snakecommunity ecc...')
      .setStyle('PARAGRAPH')
      .setRequired();

    const input2 = new Discord.TextInputComponent()
      .setCustomId('partnerato')
      .setLabel('la persona con cui hai fatto partner')
      .setPlaceholder('@M a t t o i l .#0745')
      .setStyle('PARAGRAPH')
      .setRequired();

    const row1 = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(input1);

    const row2 = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(input2);

    Modal.addComponents(row1, row2);

    interaction.showModal(Modal);
  }

  if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
    await interaction.deferUpdate();
    if (interaction.customId === 'partnerego') {
      let bravo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(' **__Partnership Eseguita__** ')
        .setDescription(
          `<a:verifygreen:1084425754554683402> _Eseguita correttamente in_ <#1091772739632763010>`,
        )
        .setColor('#0003ff')
        .setFooter(
          `${interaction.guild.name} | ` + currentDate.toLocaleString(),
          `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1084380772774985728/1084382176092635197/48115234-6DB0-400F-BA6C-681106447C87.png`,
        );
      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [bravo], ephemeral: true });

      const invito = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('invito');
      const partnerato = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('partnerato');
      let partnermb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(' **__Partnership Eseguita__** ')
        .setDescription(
          `<a:verifygreen:1084425754554683402> _Eseguita correttamente\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n> Eseguita da ${interaction.member.toString()}\n> Eseguita con_ ${partnerato}\n▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬`,
        )
        .setColor('#0003ff')
        .setFooter(
          `${interaction.guild.name} | ` + currentDate.toLocaleString(),
          `https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1084380772774985728/1084382176092635197/48115234-6DB0-400F-BA6C-681106447C87.png`,
        );
      client.channels.cache.get('1091772739632763010').send(`${invito}`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        client.channels.cache
          .get('1091772739632763010')
          .send({ embeds: [partnermb] });
      }, 2300);
    }
  }
});
```

The error message:

```
C:\Users\Utente\Documents\GitHub\snakebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:94
    if (this.deferred || this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED');
                                             ^

Error [INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ModalSubmitInteraction.reply (C:\Users\Utente\Documents\GitHub\snakebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:94:46)   
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\Documents\GitHub\snakebot\index.js:1174:43)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_ALREADY_REPLIED'
}
```

I tried to await the deferupdate and the reply but here we are

Comment: Can you add the full error message (including the error stack)?

Comment: done, check over the code

Comment: Could you please structure your question a bit more, format the error messages as code (or at least via indentation) and change your all-caps text into ordinary text?

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: Do you have more than a thousand lines of code in your `index.js` file? Do you have any other event listeners for `interactionCreate`?

Comment: no and no_____-

Answer (score 0):

By default the Discord wait 5 seconds fot the bot to reply, after those 5 seconds any response sent by the bot will not be admitted, to increase this time range (in 15 minutos) you can use the following line of code:

```
await interaction.deferReply();
```

This will send a reply to discord to tell it to wait for a reply, then to reply the interaction use:

```
interaction.followUp('Message!');
```

You can get more information about this in the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html)